# Best way for managing images of ads banners

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, theme-options

I started building a custom theme and I have a lot of ads banner image on different pages of the site. But my concern is about slowing down the site's loading speed.

What is the best way to display photo and link fields on the page?
I had previously used ACF plugin via `get_field`, but these advertising banners were loading slower than other parts of the page. Do you have any other suggestions for managing advertising banners?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you build the pages (or theme parts) that 'grab' the images. And how you get new images on the site.

If you load via Add Media, then they will get stored in YY-MM folders (see Media Settings). That's OK; they will be grabbed just nicely from there.

If you have a fixed file name for your banner (you manually update the same file, and your template/pages call that specific file), then you might be able just to upload the file.

No matter how you do it, make sure that you upload optimized JPG files, for faster loading in the browser.

Comment: No. My question is about the system architecture and the image calling type. For example, using `get_field` and `get_post_meta` and etc. Which one will be faster? What is the best method to use to create the template settings section?

Comment: You'll need to add more details to your question, with code you are using to store and access the image. Which was the point of my answer - that whatever method you use, optimized jpg will be the key factor. Whether you use get_field or get_post_meta depends on how you store the ad image. And probably not much difference in processing time for either method. WP is pretty efficient. But if you have large images, that will be the slowdown.